# Determine with what probability it is possible to guarantee that the absolute error allowed in this case will not exceed 0.02.

Tags: statistics

To determine the quality of the products manufactured by the plant, 2500 products were randomly selected. Among them there were 50 with defects. The frequency of manufacturing defective products is taken as an approximate value of the probability of manufacturing a defective product. Determine with what probability it is possible to guarantee that the absolute error allowed in this case will not exceed 0.02.

So to solve this I found population proportion = 0.02, meaning mean of sample also is 0.02. That gives me an interval of 0 - 0.04 without exceeding error of 0.02.

Besides this I don't know what more I can do to solve this. Does anyone know how to helP?